# Binance Merchant Acquiring C2B Incorrect Signature {"status":"FAIL","code":"400002","errorMessage":"Signature for this request is not valid."}

Tags: c#, .net, binance, binance-api-client

When posting to https://bpay.binanceapi.com/binancepay/openapi/v3/order
I receive response:
{"status":"FAIL","code":"400002","errorMessage":"Signature for this request is not valid."}
Check whether the signature parameter and method comply with signature algorithm requirements.

These are the methods I use to build the requests to BinancePay API in C#
It should match the API specification in https://developers.binance.com/docs/binance-pay/api-order-create-v3
I think I have good signature based on requirements in https://developers.binance.com/docs/binance-pay/api-common

```
private (string, string, string) GetData() 
{
    var nonce = GetBinanceNonce();
        
    var request = new StartDepositData
    {
            env = new StartDepositData.Env
            {
                TerminalType = TerminalType
            },
            orderTags = new StartDepositData.OrderTags 
            {
                IfProfitSharing = true
            },
            MerchantTradeNo = nonce,
            OrderAmount = (double)_data.PaymentAmount,
            Currency = _data.PaymentCurrencyId,
            Description = "BinancePay",
            GoodsDetails = new List<StartDepositData.GoodDetail>
            {
                new ()
                {
                    GoodsType = GoodsType,
                    GoodsCategory = GoodsCategory,
                    ReferenceGoodsId = _data.Reference,
                    GoodsName = "BinancePay",
                    GoodsDetail = "BinancePay"
                }
            }
        };
        
        // TODO: API Specification ambiguous, payload could be:
        // 1. var payload = body;
        // 2. var payload = timestamp + "\n" + nonce + "\n" + body + "\n";
        // 1 may just be the payload, 2 may be needed when creating signature maybe
        var timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds().ToString();
        
        var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
        var payload = body;
        var signaturePayload = timestamp + "\n" + nonce + "\n" + body + "\n";

        string signature = CreateSignature(signaturePayload, _secret);
        string hexSignature = Hex(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signature));

        return (payload, hexSignature, nonce);
    }
    
    private string CreateSignature(string payload, string secretKey)
    {
        // Initialize a new HMACSHA512 instance with the provided secret key
        var hmac = new HMACSHA512(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey));
        
        // Compute the hash of the payload
        var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));
    
        // Convert the hash to a hexadecimal string, remove any dashes typically included by BitConverter, and convert to uppercase
        return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToUpper();
    }
    
    public static string Hex(byte[] bytes)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 2);
        string hexAlphabet = "0123456789ABCDEF";

        foreach (byte b in bytes)
        {
            result.Append(hexAlphabet[b >> 4]);
            result.Append(hexAlphabet[b & 0xF]);
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
    
// A random string with 32 bytes, e.g. random ascii decimal within a-z and A-Z and loop 32 times to form a random string
private static string GetBinanceNonce(int length = 32)
{
const string chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
            .Select(s => s[new Random().Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
}
```

As for the sending it, I send it as so:

```
var (payload, signature, nonce) = GetData();
    
var timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds().ToString();

var headers = new {
                Content_Type = "application/json",
                BinancePay_Timestamp = timestamp,
                BinancePay_Nonce = nonce,
                BinancePay_Certificate_SN = _apiKey,
                BinancePay_Signature = signature
            };
var reply = await _binanceClient.PostAsync(Endpoint, new StringContent(payload), headers);
// TODO: {"status":"FAIL","code":"400002","errorMessage":"Signature for this request is not valid."}
// TODO: Check whether the signature parameter and method comply with signature algorithm requirements.
var content = await reply.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

EDIT: This works:
var timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds().ToString();

var payload = jsonRequest;
var signaturePayload = timestamp + "\n" + nonce + "\n" + jsonRequest + "\n";
private string CreateSignature(string payload)
{
byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Secret);
using (HMACSHA512 hmacsha512 = new HMACSHA512(keyBytes))
{
byte[] sourceBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);

```
        byte[] hash = hmacsha512.ComputeHash(sourceBytes);

        // Convert the hash to a hexadecimal string, remove any dashes typically included by BitConverter, and convert to uppercase
        return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToUpper();
    }
}

// A random string with 32 bytes, e.g. random ascii decimal within a-z and A-Z and loop 32 times to form a random string
private static string GetBinanceNonce(int length = 16)
{
    const string chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var randomCharacters = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
        .Select(s => s[new Random().Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());

    return BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(randomCharacters)).Replace("-", "");
}
```

string signature = CreateSignature(signaturePayload);

return (payload, signature, nonce, timestamp);

Comment: The link in your posting shows in example json with no signature.  See following which adds to the json a signature tag : https://developers.binance.com/docs/mini-program/webapp/generate-signature-offline

Comment: Hi @jdweng, I've added how I send the signature to the post, I think I already have what is mentioned in https://developers.binance.com/docs/mini-program/webapp/generate-signature-offline unless you mean something else?

Comment: @ibram-reda the title changes did not make sense in relation to the topic so I've reverted them

Comment: See https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#signed-endpoint-examples-for-post-api-v3-order-ed25519-keys

Comment: @jdweng that is for a different API - Spot Order, that has a different security requirement - SHA256, this is for BinancePay and it requires SHA512.
I've been able to generate that signature in JS as so:
`function hash_signature(query_string) {
  return crypto
      .createHmac('sha512', apiSecret)
      .update(query_string)
      .digest('hex');
}`
But it doesn't work for C# for some reason, not sure why yet

Comment: It is still Binance and you just need to change the encryption mode.  Are you running the JS and c# on same machines? There are a few reasons that c# does not give same results as JS 1) Older OS may not support encryption mode.  So c# is using OS and JS may be using OpenSSL. 2) Target Net Version of Net may not support encryption mode.  Make sure you are using a new version of Net/Core 3) The key padding may be different in c# and JS.  There are different key padding options in JS and c#.